# ¿Cómo puedo inyectar una función en el lazy-loading?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

mi objetivo es un poco mas grande pero por ahora solo quiero ejecutar una funcion antes de que se carguen los routes child, tengo esto:

**features.module.ts**

```
export function initializeApp(appInitService: AppInitService) {// esta funcion es la que quiero ejecutar
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    console.log("este si lo esta llamando");
    return appInitService.Init();
  }
}
const routes: Routes = [...];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)// aquí cargo mis routers child
  ],
  schemas:[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,// este es el tipo de provider
      useFactory: initializeApp,// aquí esta la promesa que quiero ejecutar
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppInitService]
    }
  ]
})
export class FeaturesModule { }
```

aqui tengo la funcion que se ejecutara cuando se llame el modulo, y `app.module.ts` que me llama el `FeaturesModule` por lazy loading:

**app.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      loadChildren: () =>   import('./features/features.module').then(m => m.FeaturesModule)
    },
    {
      path: 'login',
      component: LoginComponent
    }
  ];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [...,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  schemas:[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

pero no me esta funcionando debería decirme *"este si lo esta llamando"* en la consola del navegador, me estoy guiando por esta respuesta [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59236582/angular-load-routing-from-rest-service-before-initialization)

Comment: El AppInitService lo estas declarando en tu `providers` o con `({providedIn: 'root'})`?

Comment: @OscarLudick no pero ya lo hice y no sirve aun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas utilizando [`APP_INITIALIZER`](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) en un modulo cargado por `lazy-loading`, lo cual es imposible para angular cargar tu servicio. Esto debido a que como su nombre lo dice, se ejecuta una vez que inicializa la aplicación y esta solo se ejecuta una vez antes del `bootstrap`.

Tú modulo no se esta cargando hasta después de la inicialización o cuando lo solicites por lazy-load. Lo ideal es que tu `APP_INITIALIZER` se encuentre en tu `app.module.ts`.

Comment: pero entonces ¿Cómo puedo inyectar una función en el lazy-loading?

Comment: Supongo que lo que quieres, es cargar rutas dinámicas por medio de un servicio, cierto? o que es lo que quieres lograr con el ` APP_INITIALIZER`?

Comment: ese es el objetivo final

Comment: @junior Dale una revisada a este [código que realice](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-lazy-routes?file=src/app/app.module.ts), cargar las rutas lazy dinámicamente no es fácil. Si te sirve hazme lo saber para agregarlo a la respuesta.

Comment: funciona muy bien ya con eso me sirve